# Is it possible to define an implicit conversion operator to std::array?

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion

I am trying to have a C++ class that can be implicitly converted to `std::array`. Conversion works, but it is not implicit.

```
#include <array>

class A {
private:
    std::array<float, 7> data;
public:
    operator std::array<float, 7>&() { return data; }
    operator const std::array<float, 7>&() const { return data; }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a[1] = 0.5f; // fails to compile
    auto it = a.begin(); // fails to compile
    A b;
    static_cast<std::array<float, 7>>(b)[1] = 0.5f; //ok
    auto it2 = static_cast<std::array<float, 7>>(b).begin(); //ok
    return 0;
}
```

I understand the above example is quite convoluted, as it basically completely exposes a `private` member of the class. But this is an oversimplified example, I am just trying to tackle the problem of why implicit conversions to `std::array` does not work.

I have tried the above example with both `clang-3.2` and `gcc-4.8`. Neither compiles.

Even more perplexing is that if I use implicit conversion to pointer, compilation apparently succeeds:

```
operator float *() { return data.begin(); }
operator const float *() const { return data.cbegin(); }
```

But of course, this means losing the many niceties of `std::array`, which I will accept if there isn't a better solution.

Comment: Your example makes indeed absolutely no sense: just publicly inheriting from `std::array` solves all your problems. Why ever would you want to allow implicit conversion to the type of a member rather than inheriting from that type?

Comment: The example does not make sense because this is an oversimplified version. But you cannot simply proclaim that the idea of implicitly converting to `std::array` makes no sense merely from this example. What if I wish to allow implicit conversion, not to a member, but to some other object possibly dynamically constructed and stored on the heap? What if the implicit converter has its own logic and would choose a different object to return depending on the internal state of the object, all transparent to the caller? There are lots of possibilities in which this behaviour is meaningful.

Comment: I was just asking. No offence meant (nor implied). Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Not problem. I wasn't offended at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm answering your question from a comment:

> Could you please elaborate on why my conversion does not make sense? While trying to resolve operator[], why should the compiler not consider possible conversions?

Short answer, because that's how it works. A conversion operator to a built-in type can be called here, not to user-defined type.

A bit longer answer:

When an operator is used in an expression, overload resolution follows the rules laid out in `13.3.1.2`.

First:

> 2 If either operand has a type that is a class or an enumeration, a user-deﬁned operator function might be
>   declared that implements this operator or **a user-deﬁned conversion can be necessary to convert the operand
>   to a type that is appropriate for a built-in operator.** In this case, overload resolution is used to determine
>   which operator function or built-in operator is to be invoked to implement the operator [...].

`a[1]` is, for this purpose interpreted as `a.operator[](1)`, as shown in `Table 11` in the same section.

The lookup is then performed as follows:

> 3 For a unary operator @ with an operand of a type whose cv-unqualiﬁed version is T1, and for a binary
>   operator @ with a left operand of a type whose cv-unqualiﬁed version is T1 and a right operand of a type
>   whose cv-unqualiﬁed version is T2, three sets of candidate functions, designated member candidates, non-
>   member candidates and built-in candidates, are constructed as follows:
>
> > — If T1 is a complete class type, the set of member candidates is the result of the qualiﬁed lookup of
> >     T1::operator@ (13.3.1.1.1); otherwise, the set of member candidates is empty. **[1]**
> >
> > — The set of non-member candidates is the result of the unqualiﬁed lookup of operator@ in the context
> >     of the expression according to the usual rules for name lookup in unqualiﬁed function calls (3.4.2)
> >     except that all member functions are ignored. However, if no operand has a class type, only those
> >     non-member functions in the lookup set that have a ﬁrst parameter of type T1 or “reference to (possibly
> >     cv-qualiﬁed) T1”, when T1 is an enumeration type, or (if there is a right operand) a second parameter
> >     of type T2 or “reference to (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) T2”, when T2 is an enumeration type, are candidate
> >     functions.  **[2]**
> >
> > — For the operator ,, the unary operator &, or the operator ->, the built-in candidates set is empty.
> >     For all other operators, the built-in candidates include all of the candidate operator functions deﬁned
> >     in 13.6 that, compared to the given operator,
> >
> > > — have the same operator name, and
> > >       — accept the same number of operands, and
> > >       — accept operand types to which the given operand or operands can be converted according to
> > >       13.3.3.1, and **[3]**
> > >       — do not have the same parameter-type-list as any non-template non-member candidate.

The result is as follows:

- `[1]` finds nothing (there's no `operator[]` in your class
- `[2]` finds nothing (there's no free function `operator[]` and neither of operands are enumeration types)
- `[3]` finds built-in `operator[](float*, std::ptrdiff_t)` because `A` declares a conversion to `float*`

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I am looking for. One side comment: according to my copy of n3092.pdf, that table should be `Table 10` instead of `Table 11`?

Comment: @kccqzy I used n3337, it's quite possible that they differ.

Answer (score 3):

You can get them to work by overloading `operator[]` and `begin()` on `A`, or publicly inheriting from `array` (not recommended though).

The implicit conversion only works when it makes sense (say if you passed an `A` to a function that expects a `std::array<float, 7>`), not in your case. And that's a good thing if you ask me.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why my conversion does not make sense? While trying to resolve `operator[]`, why should the compiler not consider possible conversions? Quoting from [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast), this seems to be exactly the second case: “Implicit conversions are performed whenever an expression of some type `T1` is used in context that does not accept that type, but accepts some other type `T2`, in particular:[...] when the expression is used as an operand with an operator that expects `T2`”

Comment: @kccqzy your `begin` example is a bit more complicated than that statement, its 1 extra step, to go through all your conversion operators to see which matches.. and what if multiple operators match. Same with the `[]`case